# How would I use Reduce to find the intervals between the roots of a rationals polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, intervals

I'm given two poly1. I expanded both of them and got:

```
poly1 = Expand[(x - 1.1) (x - 2.2)^2 (x - 3.3)^3]
```

> ```
> 191.329 - 521.805 x + 566.607 x^2 - 316.778 x^3 + 96.8 x^4 - 15.4 x^5 + x^6
> ```

```
poly2 = Expand[(x + 1.3) (x - 2.5)^2  (x - 3.7)^3]
```

> ```
> -411.556 + 346.357 x + 86.9611 x^2 - 191.712 x^3 + 81.89 x^4 - 14.8 x^5 + x^6
> ```

Then I evaluated:

```
rat = poly1/poly2
```

> ```
> (191.329 - 521.805 x + 566.607 x^2 - 316.778 x^3 + 96.8 x^4 - 15.4 x^5 + x^6) / 
>    (-411.556 + 346.357 x + 86.9611 x^2 - 191.712 x^3 + 81.89 x^4 - 14.8 x^5 + x^6)
> ```

However, I have to use `Reduce` to find out the intervals on which the rational polynomial `rat` is positive and the intervals on which `rat` is negative. I have to reduce both polynomials, but Mathematica said it's insufficient.

This is one of the codes I tried:

```
Reduce[191.32858800000005` - 521.8052400000001` x + 566.6067` x^2 - 316.778` x^3 + 96.8` x^4 - 15.399999999999999` x^5 + x^6 > 0, x]
```

I was just wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
poly1 = (x - 1.1) (x - 2.2)^2 (x - 3.3)^3 //Rationalize; 

poly2 = (x + 1.3) (x - 2.5)^2 (x - 3.7)^3 //Rationalize;

Reduce[poly1/poly2 > 0, x]
%//N
```

> `x < -(13/10) || 11/10 < x < 11/5 || 11/5 < x < 5/2 ||  5/2 < x < 33/10 || x > 37/10`

> `x < -1.3 || 1.1 < x < 2.2 || 2.2 < x < 2.5 || 2.5 < x < 3.3 || x > 3.7`